# Save the file manually using paperclip from the params, without scaffold

Tags: hash, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, parameters

I am new to rails, I was working on paperclip gem and wanted to save the simple files, saved from paperclip.
I have the My model as follow :-

```
    class UserAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
          attr_accessible :email, :user_id, :attached_file
          has_attached_file :attached_file
          validates_attachment_presence :attached_file   
          validates_attachment_size :attached_file, :less_than => 20.megabytes   
        end
```

My controller action where the form is called :-

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @uattachment = UserAttachment.new
  end
end
```

Index view code, where the form is located

```
<%= form_for @uattachment, :url => attachment_get_link_path, :html => { :method => :post, :id => 'attachment_form', :multipart => true }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :value=>nil, :placeholder => "Enter your email here", :required => true %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :attached_file %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to use some following kind of code to save the data :-
(Code below is not the correct code, it's an excitation to tell what I want to do in my application.)

```
@uattachment = UserAttachment.new
@uattachment = params[:user_attachment]
@uattachment.save
```

Params received are as follows :-

```
(rdb:6) pp params
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dfjaskldjadslgjsoidruts48589034lsker=",
 "user_attachment"=>
  {"email"=>"testing@email.com",
   "attached_file"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcb58682ba0
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers=
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_attachment[attached_file]\"; filename=\"someimage.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="800px-Kinnaur_Kailash.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121205-8432-1fc1kpi>>},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "controller"=>"attachment",
 "action"=>"get_link"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the catch, it was pretty simple, I checked it from the scaffolded assignment,

```
def index
  @uattachment = UserAttachment.new(params[:user_attachment])
  @uattachment.save
end
```

And you get the golden words in response "true".